# Laravel Registration controller only to allow specific emails to register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I've got this validator

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

& I want it to only accept emails from a list i've got. there are 300 emails, which I have and I was wondering whats the best way to do that?

Ive tried:

```
    $allowed_emails = array ('one@two.three')
return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'in_array:allowed_emails', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
```

Which says that email is not in allowed emails array &

```
return Validator::make($data,$allowed_emails = array ('one@two.three'), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
```

Which allows anything to pass.

How can i solve problem?

Comment: use 'email' => ['required|in:' . implode(',', $allowed_emails)] instead of in_array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599790/3266552

Comment: i've done this before, and forgot to import rule, works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a Rule object (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-rule-objects) in order to make a custom validation rule.

Inside this object, you'll be able to write all the logic you need for your specific use case.

**[EDIT]**

To complete my answer, this is how you do it with a custom rule object:

```php
$data = [
    'name' => 'HelloWorld',
    'email' => 'hello@world.de',
    'password' => 'secret123',
    'password_confirmation' => 'secret123'
];

$val = \Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', new AllowedEmailsRule(), 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
]);
```

And the `AllowedEmailsRule` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class AllowedEmailsRule implements Rule
{
    private $emails = [
        'abc@abc.com',
        'hello@world.de',
        'foo@bar.co.uk'
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return in_array($value, $this->emails);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Your email address is not allowed.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of Rule Object with relation to the question. The link might break soon for any reason and your answer would become un-usable. Thanks.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin In deed you are right, I should have done it less lazely. In addition, I should mention that the answer of Hafez Divandri is more appropriate since it doesn't involve the use of a custom rule.

Comment: But yours was accepted by the OP so its okay. Others may find Hafez Divandri's answer useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Rule::in` like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $allowed_emails = ['one@two.three']

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => [
            'required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users',
            Rule::in($allowed_emails)
        ],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-in) form more info.

Comment: While the answer gave an alternative way of solving the problems. Providing even a short explanation would help anyone know that you intend the user to understand your answer in relation to the question. Also, using the word "Try" in your answer is an indication that you possibly do not understand the question or you're not certain of the answer you gave.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin thank you for your comment, I thought about adding more explanation but couldn't find anything more useful to add but a link to docs. I'm  disagree with you about meaning of "Try" but I would appreciate your edit on my post.